# Proving given equality using integral theorems

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let’s assume $F$ is a function defined over real numbers set, and differentiable all over its domain.

Also, assume $f$ is a continuous derivative of $F$.

How could we prove that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{i}{n^2}\right) f\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)\right) = F(1) - \int_{0}^{1} F(x) dx$$

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

The limit of a Riemann sum is equal to the definite integral with limits from $0$ to $1$, that is
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right) = \int_0^1f(x)dx.$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{n^2}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)=\int_0^1xf(x)dx.$$
Use integration-by-parts on the above and you'll get your answer.

Comment: How did you conclude the second line of equality from the first line?

Comment: @Jigsaw The summation is over $k$, so you can take one of the $n$ outside the summation.

Comment: Still I am confused: how did you change that $\frac1n$ into $\frac{k}{n^2}$? And also how did you conclude the third line from the second line?

Comment: $\frac{k}{n^2}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right) = \frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{k}{n}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)$. Is it clear now?